# NodeJS net package error when client writing to server

Tags: node.js, sockets

So I took the following code https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757 example and modified it slightly such that the client writes data to the server. This should be doable since the client socket does support a write. In one of my use cases the client sends a fair amount of data from the client to server in which case I get an ECONNRESET error. Attached are client and server snippets. I was wondering if anyone has seen this and if they know what is going wrong under the covers.

Here is a copy of my client:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket({writeable: true}); //writeable true does not appear to help 

client.on('close', function() {

    console.log('Connection closed');
});

client.on('error', function(err) {

    console.error('Connection error: ' + err);
    console.error(new Error().stack);
});

client.connect(5900, '127.0.0.1', function() {

    var count = 0;

    console.log('Connected');

    for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

        client.write('' + i + '');

        //bufferSize does not seem to be an issue
        //console.info(client.bufferSize);
    }
});
```

---

and my server:

```
var net = require('net');

var count = 0;

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    socket.pipe(socket);  //With this uncommented I get an ECONNRESET exception after 14299 writes with it commented it hangs after 41020 writes

    socket.on('data', function(data) {

        console.info(count++);  //This makes it occur sooner
        //count++;

        //maxConnections is not the issue
        //server.getConnections(function(err, count) {

            //console.info('count = ' + count);
        //});
    });

    socket.on('close', function() {

        console.info('Socket close');
    });

    socket.on('error', function(err) {

        console.error('Socket error: ' + err + ', count = ' + count);
        console.error(new Error().stack);
    });
});

server.listen(5900, '127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 0):

When the client has finished sending data in the `for` loop inside its `connect` event handler, there is nothing more for it to do so it exits.  That terminates the connection, and the server gets an `ECONNRESET` to inform it that the connection has been broken.

If you want the client to hang around after it has finished sending then give it some reason to stay alive.  Registering a `data` event handler on the client socket is one possibility.

Comment: I don't think that was the problem.  The server only received about 10,000 not anywhere near the 100,000 which the client was sending.  In my example to implement all of the listeners: event listeners close, data, drain, end, lookup, timeout.  I have noticed that the client periodically receives a data event and as well as a drain event.  Since these did not exist it resulted in the client error.  Thanks for looking and responding!

Comment: TCP is allowed to deliver the content of multiple writes in a single read so even in a successful run your server will not see 100,000 `data` events.  To track how much the server has received, sum the length of the `data` arguments it is given.  It should be 488890 (delivered by 42188 events in my last test). The client gets data because the server is echoing back everything it receives. If the client has not registered a handler or a pipe() destination then that data will be discarded, but that will not break the connection.